# OperationalError: attempt to write a readonly database,

Tags: linux, sqlite, flask

I am working on flask app and deployed to linux server when I am doing Insert Query its giving OperationalError: attempt to write a readonly database, in error log 
import sqlite3 as sql
def insertUser(username,password,email,phone):
    with sql.connect("/var/www/FlaskApp/database.db") as con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO user (username,password,email,phone) VALUES (?,?,?,?)", (username,password,email,phone))
        con.commit()

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the user running the flask application does not have permission to write to `/var/www/FlaskApp/database.db`. Have you checked your file permissions. It's perhaps best to have the file be owned by the user running your Flask application.

Comment: How I allow permission to this file its only reading but not writing on it, I have done chmod it sh-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 38912 Apr  8 17:36 database.db
owing

Comment: What user is your Flask application running as? That user needs to own the file. Currently it appears to be owned by root.